# How to extract a few lines from a pdf files?

Tags: python, pdf, cpu-word

I have a **PDF file** that goes like this:

Q1. How many planets are there?
A. 1
B. 3
C. 8
D. 9

Answer: 8

Explanation: bla bla bla

Q2. How many moons are there?
A. 1
B. 3
C. 8
D. 9

Answer: 1

Explanation: bla bla bla

Q3. Who is Alex's friend?
A. Adam
B. Donald
C. Joe
D. Jack

Answer: Joe

Explanation: bla bla bla

And so on upto Q100

*How to remove the Answer and Explanation and only get the Questions, i.e. in the following format*

Q1. How many planets are there?
A. 1
B. 3
C. 8
D. 9

Q2. How many moons are there?
A. 1
B. 3
C. 8
D. 9

Q3. Who is Alex's friend?
A. Adam
B. Donald
C. Joe
D. Jack

.... and so on upto Q100

Comment: Are the question, answer and explanations in separate lines in the pdf file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: there are several ways to do this `pymupdf`, `pdfminer`, etc. Have you experimented with any of them?

Comment: @Costa. Yes the Question and answers and explanations are in different lines. Moreover the Question, Answer and Explanations could span multiple lines and the number of lines they span/occupy are different for different questions. (i.e say Q1 may have a 2 line question, 1 line answer and 5 line explanation, Q6 may have 10 line question, 5 line answer and 30 line explanation). However, what is common across all is every Question begins with a Q'n'(i.e Q1, Q2... Q100), Every Answer begins with a heading "Answer:" and Every explanation begins with a "Explanation:"

Answer (score 0):

OK, After a lot of trial and error was abe to figure out
First I converted the PDF to txt file
then used the code (pic attached)

Basically converted the file to lists and used regex to append only needed outputs. (input File was UTF). A very dumb way of doing it, but it works!!!

[image: Converted the file to lists and used regex to append only needed outputs]